# How to convert an OpenCV Mat that has been written in an xml file back into an image?

Tags: c++, xml, matlab, opencv

I wrote some code to generate an .xml file that contains the RGB data from a Mat file in OpenCV. I would like to recreate this image in MATLAB from the data points in the xml file. I am however unsure of the formatting of the xml file, since when I open it it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0?>
<opencv_storage>
<myMatrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>116</rows>
    <cols>116</cols>
    <dt>u</dt>
    <data>
      97 101 97 98 99 97 ...
    </data>
    </myMatrix>
    </opencv_storage>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert it to matlab format within opencv.

read it in using the Filestorage:

```
Mat m;
Filestorage fs("m.xml", Filestorage::READ);
fs["myMatrix"] >> m;
```

then print it out (or write to a file) in matlab format:

```
// 2.4 version
cerr << format(m,"MATLAB") << endl;
// 3.0 version
cerr << format(m,cv::Formatter::FMT_MATLAB) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a xml to struct converter such as the following:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

this will allow you to convert the data into a struct, then you can simply reshape your data:

```
pic = reshape(struct.data, struct.rows, struct.cols)
image(pic)
```

Note: This isn't out of the box code.